# Flex application versioning

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, build

I'm not referring to CVS or SVN! The thing I would like to do is:

- I want to have a version number of the application ex. 0.0.120
- I want to see this version number only in the About box or similar
- This version number should change everityme I hit debug or release. ex. my version was 0.0.120, after I hit debug in the FlexBuilder, the versionNumber should change to 0.0.121, but If I press Release Build, then the version should change to 0.1.0
- The first number changes only when I manually change it

Don't know how is this possible but if you have a tip, let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this article http://www.igorcosta.org/?p=220. I use this method to keep tract of compilation date of my swfs.

Credits goes to Paul Sivtsov.

Answer (score 1):

I think Flex Builder doesn't have this out of the box, but you can build ant script for that and build your application with it:

http://blog.nirav.name/2008/02/how-to-auto-increament-version-build-id.html

Answer (score 1):

This is typically something you support with frameworks such as maven.
There is actually a maven plugin for flex [here](http://www.servebox.org/maven-flex-plugin/)

mico's trick is nice though